# app_dev.php not loading and only shows the source code in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, puphpet

I just installed the symfony standard edition using [puphpet.com](https://puphpet.com/) but when I try to open the app_dev.php the browser show me the source code that has inside the app_dev file and should me the welcome page:

[image]

The app/check.php all is ok.

Comment: You need to make sure you have PHP installed and that your server is configured to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent browser from displaying php code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770318/how-to-prevent-browser-from-displaying-php-code)

Comment: All who wrote about php is not installed, Look to the question careful >> app/check.php all is ok, so means the file is executed, so php is installed

Comment: Ok, then there is a problem with the puphpet enviroment.

Comment: Check app_dev.php permissions, compare it with check.php

Comment: Maybe your file is not a .php file, perhaps .php.txt ?

Comment: The problem was fixed only restarting the enviropment (puphpet) "vagrant reload"